# How to cancel asynchronous method called using Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I want to know how to cancel\stop asynchronous method called using reactive extensions using the `TakeUntil`.

So I want to be able to cancel\stop the following method:

```
this.booksService.Search(searchText)
                 .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                 .Subscribe(results =>
                 {
                    this.books.Clear();
                    this.books.AddRange(results);
                 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return from `Subscribe()` is an `IDisposable`, when you dispose the value, like so:

```
var searchSub = this.booksService
                    .Search(searchText) ...
                    .Subscribe( ... );
// do something else
searchSub.Dispose();
```

the subscription is stopped. Does that actually stop the underlying booksSevice search? That depends on the implementation. If done w/ `Observable.Create` then it's quite possible to get that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tell `booksService` to cancel the search. The `Search` method starts the search and also returns an `IObservable`. When the search is complete `OnNext` will be called on the `IObservable`. There is some asynchronous code started in `Search` that you need to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to change the search method to an asynchronous call that takes a CancellationToken as the second argument. You can then convert this to an Observable sequence via Observable.ToAsync.  Calling dispose on this observable will then trigger the cancellation of the CancellationToken. Doing this allows you to easily pass the token onto asynchronous web calls etc.

```
public Task Search(string searchText, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    // Pass the token on to the async webclient request etc.
}

var searchSub = Observable.ToAsync(c => this.booksService.Search(searchText, c))
                .Subscribe( ... );
// do something else
searchSub.Dispose();
```